# Can anyone tell me the mechanism behind this reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry

$\ce{1-octene -> octan-1-ol}$

The reaction occurs in the presence of $\ce{ROOR}$ and $\ce{HBr}$.
There is no information about temperature.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry Beta! Please see [our homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/142/22) Try to include an indication of your attempts to solve this, maybe a partial mechanism. I can reopen this once edited. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have only trivial knowledge of organic chemistry, but here goes:

Assuming ROOR represents a peroxide, we have homolytic cleavage of ROOR to form $\ce RO^{.} and ^{.}OR$. Afterwards, these radicals interact with HBr to produce ROH and a Br radical. The ROH then is protonated on the alcohol group to make a better leaving group, and the $\ce {H2O}$ is cleaved, leaving a radical R group, which is then attacked by a Br radical. Water is then added to the alkene oct-1-ene to form octan-1-ol.

Comment: HBr will add to the octene and the product will be 1-bromo-octane. This in turn can be hydrolyzed in a second (and separate!) reaction with water to give 1-octanol. R-O-O-R acts a a radical starter only, the addition of HBr is a radical chain reaction.